# number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length error

Tags: r, regex, list, pattern-matching

I have a vector of addresses (a small snippet is shown below)

```
df=c("westmoorings east","chaguanas proper","bloody bay" ,"westmooorings",   
"el doraldo","rousillac34") (full length=5432)
```

and another vector of reference cities/areas (see snippet below)

```
areas=c("arima","port of spain","chaguanas") (full length=20)
```

what I would like to go is group the addresses in `df` by the areas in the `areas` vector for example the address `chaguanas proper` would be grouped under `chaguanas`. I am using a list to store the results. The code I am using to accomplish this is :

```
L=list() 
for(i in 1:length(areas)){
    ind=grep(paste(areas[i]),df)
    L[i]=df[ind] 
    df[-ind] #updates the df to exclude all addresses already stored in L[i]
```

}

The problem lies in the line *`L[i]=df[ind]`*. I am getting the error "*`number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`*" Can anyone help with this? I am getting the pattern matching to work but storing the results in the list components brings up that error. I am using R by the way.

Comment: If there is no match, the grep returns NULL or `numeric(0)`.  I guess you need a `if/else`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this after some slight changes on your code:

```
#Data
df=c("westmoorings east","chaguanas proper","bloody bay" ,"westmooorings",
     "el doraldo","rousillac34")
areas=c("arima","port of spain","chaguanas")
#Code
L=list() 
for(i in 1:length(areas)){
  ind=which(grepl(paste(areas[i]),df))
  if(length(ind)!=0)
  {
    L[i]=df[ind]
    df[-ind] 
  }
}
```

Output:

```
L

[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
[1] "chaguanas proper"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can pre initialize 'L' with the `length` of 'areas' and use the `if` condition as in the comments

```
L <- vector("list", length(areas))
for(i in seq_along(areas)){
  ind <-  grep(areas[i],df )
  if(length(ind) > 0) {
    L[[i]]  <- df[ind]
     df <- df[-ind] 
  }
}


L
#[[1]]
#NULL

#[[2]]
#NULL

#[[3]]
#[1] "chaguanas proper"
```

NOTE: This answers the OP's question posted

---

If we want to do this vectorized way, a very easier option is (no loops and the `grep` is called only once)

```
grep(paste(areas, collapse="|"), df, value = TRUE)
#[1] "chaguanas proper"
```

#### data

```
df <- c("westmoorings east","chaguanas proper","bloody bay" ,"westmooorings",
     "el doraldo","rousillac34")
areas <- c("arima","port of spain","chaguanas")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using `sapply` would be easier here :

```
L <- sapply(areas, function(x) grep(x, df, value = TRUE))
L

#$arima
#character(0)

#$`port of spain`
#character(0)

#$chaguanas
#[1] "chaguanas proper"
```

The same using `tidyverse` functions would be :

```
purrr::map(areas, ~stringr::str_subset(df, .x))
```

Answer (score 0):

The R error you're seeing happens often when you get your indexing syntax slightly wrong. In this case it seems that you want to loop over the elements of your area vector, but in your original code you're asking R to place the return values in the (upper) "indexing" level of your list "L" , i.e. `L[i]`. In fact, you should be placing the return values in the (lower) "values" level of your list "L", i.e. `L[[i]]`. See examples:

```
> Output_listA <- list() 
> for(i in 1:length(areas)){
     Output_listA[[i]] <- grep(areas[i],df, value=TRUE)
     }
> Output_listA
[[1]]
character(0)

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
[1] "chaguanas proper"
```

In Output_listA you see the use of `grep()` with the parameter "value=TRUE". This will return a list of matches. But maybe you just want an index to do further manipulations? Then use `grepl()` as below:

```
> Output_listB <- list() 
> for(i in 1:length(areas)){
     Output_listB[[i]] <- grepl(areas[i],df)
     }
> Output_listB
[[1]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[2]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[3]]
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

> df[ Output_listB[[3]] ]
[1] "chaguanas proper"
```

Finally, you can let the `lapply()` function do the work for you. Below the use of `grep()` is shown, but you could just as easily use `grepl()`:

```
> lapply(areas, FUN = function(x) grep(x, df, value=TRUE) )
[[1]]
character(0)

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
[1] "chaguanas proper"
```